# How to load an openSUSE live USB?

Tags: opensuse, live-usb

I've followed the instructions here:

[Create a Live USB stick using Windows](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Create_a_Live_USB_stick_using_Windows)

I've managed to get the openSUSE loading screen up. One of the options is to install openSUSE the other is to boot from HDD, neither of which let me load it as a live usb.

[This](http://software.opensuse.org/421/en) is the iso I downloaded, and the section below says:

> ## How to Proceed
>
> After having successfully downloaded the ISO image(s), create a  bootable USB stick or burn the image(s) to a DVD (or a CD if the chosen image fits).

Which makes me think there isn't a separate iso for booting to a live USB.

As far as I remember, doing this with Linux Mint and Ubuntu you load straight into the OS and don't need to install it.

So how do I load a Live USB of openSUSE?

Comment: Which image did you download: the network installation image (which surely isn't usable live) or the DVD image (which it isn't clear to me whether it's usable as a live image)?

Comment: @Gilles the DVD version, which fits the instructions I read `These instructions explain how to create a bootable USB stick to install openSUSE from the LiveCD isos or from the DVD`

Comment: There is no official LiveCD for openSUSE Leap, although you can create one with SUSE studio or just use one of already existing like https://susestudio.com/a/fm2w15/leap-live

Comment: @contemplator that would make a good answer

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple way to make live USB  :

--> download. LinuxLive  USB Creator 
http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download

--> after installing it. Open it. There are 3 steps..

1)choose USB disk

2) select the ISO file / your Linux source

3) click on the  thunder. Icon

[image]

I think the version you have downloaded  May not have live mode facility.

Try to download this one 
http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/iso/openSUSE-13.2-GNOME-Live-x86_64.iso

Comment: Does this work with openSUSE?

Comment: Yeah. It will work. With OpenSUSE.

Comment: Praveenvs, when I asked about it 'working' I was more concerned with after creating the live usb. Once I've done that, I get to a screen that says I can install it, but I don't want to install it I just want a Live USB.

Comment: Which version of. OpenSUSE you have.

Comment: The one I linked to in my question, namely:  openSUSE Leap 42.1

Comment: Do you have followed the steps right. Like in the image

Comment: I think the version you have downloaded v Mar not have live mode facility.

Comment: Try to download this one http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/13.2/iso/openSUSE-13.2-GNOME-Live-x86_64.iso

Comment: THANK YOU! That looks like it will work! Please add that to your answer, it's the **most** important part.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another method:
First, head to https://rufus.akeo.ie/ and download it to your computer.
Second, plugin your USB, open Rufus. Then, remember to choose "Create a bootable disk using image", choose the openSUSE iso file.
Click start, then try to boot from USB again.

Comment: How is this different to what I've tried already?

Comment: I don't know what could be the exact cause. But to creat a Live USB for any Linux distro, I just use Linux Live USB Creator as @praveen-v-s mentioned, or Rufus or Unetbootin.